# How to make a GUI program which iterate numbers in a file?

Tags: java, file, user-interface

I want to make an GUI program which write in a file x numbers from y.

E.g: if y=103 and x=100, the output is "103 104 105 106...202"(100 numbers).

I tried this code, but when I run it and submit some numbers, the file still remain empty.

Probably the problem is at the `void filein()`.

```
package me;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.*;    
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class program {

    static PrintStream OUT = System.out;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        startGUI();
                }
        });
    }
        private static void startGUI() {

            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setTitle("Text Writer");
            {
                    setupWindowContent(window);
            }
            window.pack();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void setupWindowContent(JFrame window) {

            JPanel content = new JPanel();
            final JLabel lblEnterSmthng = new JLabel("Enter the first number and the iterate limit:");
            final JTextField txtField1 = new JTextField(30);
            final JTextField txtField2 = new JTextField(30);
            JButton btnOk = new JButton("Ok");
            final JLabel labelLastText = new JLabel();
            content.add(lblEnterSmthng);
            content.add(txtField1);
            content.add(txtField2);
            content.add(btnOk);
            content.add(labelLastText);
            window.setContentPane(content);

            ActionListener submitAction = new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
                            String txt = txtField1.getText();
                            String txt2 = txtField2.getText();
                            int i = Integer.parseInt(txt);
                            int serii = Integer.parseInt(txt2);
                            if(!txt.isEmpty()){                                    
                                labelLastText.setText(txt);                                    
                        }
                    }

                    void filein(int i, int serii) throws IOException {                                  
                            FileInputStream in = null;
                            FileOutputStream out = null;
                            try {                                    
                                out = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/mihai/OneDrive/Desktop/Text.txt");
                                System.out.print(i + serii);

                                for(i=i;i<i+serii-1;i++) {                                       
                                    out.write(i);
                                 }                                    
                             }finally {                                    
                                if (out != null) {
                                   out.close();
                                }                                 
                             }                                                               
                    }
            };              
            btnOk.addActionListener(submitAction);
            txtField1.addActionListener(submitAction);
            txtField2.addActionListener(submitAction);
       }                        
   }
```

I do not know what details to give you.

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging it? Does `filein` get executed? Do you see any exception?

Comment: So where do you call the method filein()?

Comment: When I hover this method the editor say me:"The method filein(int, int) from the type new ActionListener(){} is never used locally"

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: "is never used", "what do you suggest" -> to call the function. When do you want to write in file ? when the button is pressed then call `filein(i, serii);` inside `actionPerformed`

Comment: ok, thx, i will try

Comment: When I call the method inside `actionPerformed`, I get this: "Unhandled exception type IOException"